# Cross-compiling c++ project using CMake for AARCH64 Ubuntu system

Tags: c++, c, compilation, cmake, arm

The current issue I am experiencing is setting up CMAKE for cross-compiling for the AARCH64 environment. The C++ project does reference some other third party libraries such as boost for its compiling.

I have read the documentation, but it is not really clear on the step-by-step procedure on what needs to be done in order to cross-compile using CMAKE for aarch64 on a x86_64 environment.

I have read that I need the rootfs of the aarch64 system, others it states I dont need it and only need the c++ compiler and cross headers/libraries.

At the current moment I am trying to compile the project on a Mustang board. But it runs in to issues with referencing the installed libraries for the x86_64 system.

If there is a person or site that could detail setup by step what would need to be done to this environment in order to get the entire project to cross-compile for aarch64 on a x86_64 system. I would greatly appreciate it.